# How can I modify attributes of objects in a Django queryset for data presentation without modifying the original object?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-viewsets

I want to present a list of objects for which I want to filter/modify one attribute during the presentation of the data. Something close to an annotation, but I did not manage to do it with annotations.
These are the models

```
class Airline (models.Model):
   name = models.CharField()
   destinations = models.ManyToManyField("city")
   customers = models.ManyToManyField("user")

class City (models.Model):
   name = models.CharField()
   country = models.CharField()
 
class User (models.Model):
   name = models.CharField()
   preferredDestinations = models.ManyToManyField("city")
```

I want, for a given user, present a list of the Airlines the user is customer, and for each Airline present the list of destinations for the Airline. But instead of presenting all the airline destinations I only want to present the destinations preferred by the user.

e,g,

```
Airline1.destinations=["New York", "London", "Paris", "Madrid]
Airline2.destinations=["Madrid", "Barcelona", "Rome", "Berlin", "London"]

User1.preferredDestinations=["Madrid", "Barcelona", "Paris"]
```

With user1 being a customer of Airline1 and Airline 2, I want the page to present a table showing to which of the user preferred destination every airline flies to. I.e. I do not want to see all the destinations the airline flies to, only the ones the user is interested: E.g.

```
Welcome User1!
These are your airlines that fly to your preferred destinations
Airline    | Destination |
| -------- | --------  |
| Airline1 | Madrid    |
|          | Paris     |
| -------- | --------  |
| Airline2 | Madrid    |
|          | Barcelona |
```

In the view I get a queryset for the user

`airlineSet = Airline.objects.filter(customers=user.id)`

And in the template

```
{% for airline in airlineSet %}
  <tr>
  <td>
   {{ airline.name }}
  </td>
  <td>
    {% for city in airline.destinations.all %}
    <li>
      {{ city }}
    </li>
    {% endfor %} 
  </td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

This presents all the destinations for the airline, but I want a subset which is the intersection of `airline.destinations` and `user.preferredDestinations`

I tried to get the subset and put it in the attribute `destination` of the objects in the queryset `airlineSet`, but that actually modified the original Airline objects, and messed up the database.
I though of creating annotations in the queryset with the subset of the cities, but it seems it's limited what you can add with annotations (count, max, mix). I do not know how to add such annotations.

In addition, in the example above I put a few cities, but it actually can be a quite long number of cities, for the airline and for the user, and I want to limit how many cities are presented in the overview page to not over-flood with a big list of cities, but showing a short list (when I click on the airline it would show the whole union)

I made the intersection in the template `{% if city in preferredDestinations %}` but that has limitations for limiting the number of cities.

Is this something doable on the View?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is

```
{% for airline in airlineSet %}
  <tr>
  <td>
   {{ airline.name }}
  </td>
  <td>
    {% for city in airline.destinations.all %}
    
      {% if city in user.preferredDestinations %}
        <li>
          {{ city }}
        </li>
      {% endif %}
    
    {% endfor %} 
  </td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

And not to show too many cities I would recommend using pagination.

Comment: Thanks, this is actually what I have right now. My issue is that 1 airline can take the whole screen and even more, requiring scrolling to see other airlines. 
For usability, I'd rather want to see the list of airlines in one page, with a short list of the cities. I do not want to paginate to see the other airlines.
I tried with `{% for city in airline.destinations.all|slice:"[:10]" %}` to limit how many cities are presented, but then, if none of the 10 first cities are in the user's preferred list, nothing is presented.